# How to define custom Styles for H1, H2, h3 in MaterialCSS using createTheme?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, material-design, next.js13

I have a **NextJS**-application using **MaterialCSS** and the following **theme** created:

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

export const darkTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: 'dark',
  },
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          color: 'white',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export const lightTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: 'light',
  },
});
```

I understand how to overrite styles for Mui-Components.
How can I define custom styles for  elements in my themes, that I have a different h3-style for the dark theme than on the light theme?

Answer (score 0):

```
const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    h3: {
      fontSize: 30,
    },
    subtitle1: {
      fontSize: 12,
    },
    body1: {
      fontWeight: 500,
    },
    button: {
      fontStyle: 'italic',
    },
  },
});
```

Documentation:
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/typography/#variants